# Reading base64/zlib encoded string from actionscript in python

Tags: python, actionscript, base64, zlib

I have a string saved to a database that is encoded by Actionscript by base64ing it and then zlib compressing it.

An example string is this: "eNrj4mZkrShgWdHBx1mUmJfNosQIACUhBCI="

If I unzip and un base64 this via Actionscript, I get what I expect:

{"xp": 656398, "rank": 34}

But, I need to be able to also read this server-side. For now I'm using Python but I'd be open to a working PHP solution or similar.

So far in Python I have tried this:

```
import base64
import zlib

s = 'eNrj4mZkrShgWdHBx1mUmJfNosQIACUhBCI='

print s.decode("base64").decode("zlib")
```

It looks like Actionscript adds some extra bits into the header, but my Python is not strong enough to defeat this :) Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Actionscript first takes an AS Object and converts it to a ByteArray, before zlib compressing it and base64ing it. It looks like this is what is generating the extra header/mangled data info.

Comment: Please, think about it again and tell us with 100 % certainty: in which order to you perform the encoding? First zip, then b64 for transport, or the other way round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash could be mangling this, but you should share an example from Actionscript that creates and checks this data.

If you're using a 3rd party library, it might be using an alternate characterset than Python is expecting.

if you're using the official library, it seems that Actionscript implements UTF8 and ascii differently.  ( there are different methods here - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html)

it's much easier to just see the actionscript and note if there's an issue with the library or your code, than try to reverse engineer this.

I think it also might be worth trying to bugfix this in reverse...

```
import base64
import zlib

flash =  "eNrj4mZkrShgWdHBx1mUmJfNosQIACUhBCI="

original = '{"xp": 656398, "rank": 34}'
encoded = original.encode('zlib').encode('base64')
decoded = encoded.decode('base64').decode('zlib')
print original
print encoded
print decoded
```

Can I also ask why you're even doing this ?

1- unless your packets are much bigger, you're not going to be saving much bandwidth.  in fact, compression on small payloads can actually increase the size.

2- assuming this is web based, you should be able to have the server do this on the fly.

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure Flash/actionscript is mangling this by adding some extra characters in as I stated originally. I'll try and find the exact Actionscript code that is used to encode and post that too.

Comment: To answer your questions, yes, most of our packets are much larger.. this is the smallest example I could find, but most packets uncompressed are several hundred kb in size. For 2, we have several million rows of data archived which we want to convert over to a new system, so there is no live system to run this on. I could build an AS rig that queries the DB for the strings, reads them, and then rewrites, but I was really hoping to do this server-side with python.

Comment: understood about the archives - and yeah, this would be really fast in python. i fear it will be a lot of pain to try and figure out what is happening without the flash code though.  flash could be using a different payload, or padding the payload, or it could be encoding some different representation of the string.  

hopefully you can find that flash, because i honestly want to know whats going on.  ( if you have a .swf , we might be able to decompile it too... )

Answer (score 1):

If the string is first base64-ed and then zipped, decoding it should be the other way around!

Your example and output strings don't match;

```
In [1]: t = '{"xp": 656398, "rank": 34}'

In [2]: t.encode('base64')
Out[2]: 'eyJ4cCI6IDY1NjM5OCwgInJhbmsiOiAzNH0=\n'

In [3]: t.encode('zlib').encode('base64')
Out[3]: 'eJyrVqooULJSMDM1M7a00FFQKkrMywbyjU1qAVupBsE=\n'

In [4]: t.encode('base64').encode('zlib')
Out[4]: 'x\x9cK\xad\xf42Iv\xf64\xf3t\x894\xf4\xcb\xf25\xf5w.O\xf7\xcc\xf3\xcaH\xca-\xce\xf4\xcft\xac\xf2\xf30\xb0\xe5\x02\x00\xe3E\x0b\xd7'
```

The given input string '{"xp": 656398, "rank": 34}' does not produce the example output (see Out[3] and Out[4]).

You should also note that in this case the `base64` encoded string is *longer* than the original, and the additional `zlib` encoding is longest. Compressing strings this short is usually not worth the overhead.

If we take your example output and process it, this is what we get;

```
In [5]: s = 'eNrj4mZkrShgWdHBx1mUmJfNosQIACUhBCI='

In [6]: s.decode('base64')
Out[6]: 'x\xda\xe3\xe2fd\xad(`Y\xd1\xc1\xc7Y\x94\x98\x97\xcd\xa2\xc4\x08\x00%!\x04"'

In [7]: s.decode('base64').decode('zlib')
Out[7]: '\n\x0b\x01\x05xp\x04\xa8\x88\x0e\trank\x04"\x01'
```

You can clearly see the texts 'xp' and 'rank' in the output. And the '"' near the end could be interpreted as the integer 34.

It seems that your actionscript does some mangling of the data before encoding and compressing it.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your Python script is decoding in the wrong order. If what you say about the encoding order is correct, first base64, then zlib, you must decode in the opposite order:

```
print s.decode("zlib").decode("base64")
```

Comment: It can't be; the result of base64 then zlib isn't text :)

Comment: @Tosh says two times that he first b64 encodes, then zips. Which makes sense.

Comment: Well, trying to un-zip then base64-decode the sample data only gives an error because it's clearly not zlib-compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Tosh, you say that you first base64-encode data and then zip it before storing it to the database. This is fine so far. After zipping the data, it is binary data. Hence, I assume that you have stored this data in binary format in the database. Now you show us a string:

> An example string is this: "eNrj4mZkrShgWdHBx1mUmJfNosQIACUhBCI="

This, according to you, represents the zipped data. Now, there is a contradiction. On the one hand zipped data is binary data, on the other hand you clearly show us a string here that resulted from base64-encoding (as you can infer from the '=' in the end).

You confuse something.

Comment: It is stored in a MEDIUMTEXT field in a mysql database. The unzip and unbase64 order is correct, my belief is that actionscript does not use standard encodings and leaves something extra in the zip header.